# issue from bsrn data retrieval via ftp

Tags: pvlib

I was able to retrive data from (BSRN) after receiving username and password! After a week, it led to the issue shown below! Any suggestions on how to solve it?

```
data, metadata = pvlib.iotools.get_bsrn(  
    start=pd.Timestamp(2020,2,1), end=pd.Timestamp(2020,2,2),   
    station='BOS', username='redacted', password='redacted')
data
```

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: I get the same error and believe it to be an issue with the FTP server, feel free to write to the BSRN to let them know. Also, NEVER post username/passwords on public sites like StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks so much Adam! I will contact the BSRN. Also, thank you mentioned about the username and password, I forget completely! Thanks again